# ng-include with a variable for src

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I would like to change the ng-includes src with a variable. Currently this is what I have.

```
 <div class='alignRightCenter' id='rightContent'>
    <ng-include src="'{{view}}'"> </ng-include>
</div>
```

And here is the controller:

```
ctrl.controller('contentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.view = "partials/setListName.tpl.html";
  }]);
```

Unfortunately I can not use a ng-view because it is already being used to get me to this page.
Is it possible to make something like this work?

Comment: have you tried ng-src="{{view}}" ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
<ng-include src="view"> </ng-include>
```

-----------------OR----------------------

You can do this way,

View:

```
<div data-ng-include data-ng-src="getPartial()"></div>
```

Controller:

```
function AppCtrl ($scope) {
  $scope.getPartial = function () {
      return 'partials/issues.html';
  }
}
```

Comment: `<div data-ng-include data-ng-src="getPartial()"></div>` does not work for me. `getPartial()` isn't rised, but `<ng-include src="getPartial()"></ng-include>` works!

Comment: @Chaki_Black Try `<div ng-include src="getPartial()"></div>` instead of `<div data-ng-include data-ng-src="getPartial()"></div>`

Answer (score 11):

Like this. You need to use single quotes and +, like you would in JavaScript.

```
<ng-include src="'/path/to/template'+ my.variable +'.html'"></ng-include>
```