# Fill the src attribute of ng-iclude with data from model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Why do I get the error message:

```
Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: '{{ content.src }}'
Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.
```

with this syntax:

```
<div id="content" class="content">
     <ng-include src="'{{ content.src }}'"/>
</div>
```

And the model is

```
$scope.content = {};
$scope.content.src = "content.html";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in some of my projects with syntax like:

```
<ng-include src="content.src"/>
```

The `src` attribute doesn't need the bracket notation, you can just reference scope variables. Single quotes are needed only if you are using a string literal.

Comment: Slow in what way? When requesting the html fragment?

Comment: yes, it is a delay here, it takes more than 1 second.

Comment: Don't think it's anything to with `ng-include` , I use it all over the place and there's no delay, the fragments come back from the server fast and are rendered almost immediately. Seems like maybe an issue with the server, if you look at the network tab in Chrome Dev Tools as the page loads, you can see when each http request is fired, and how long it takes to get back a response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way : `<ng-include src="{{ content.src }}"/>`

Something like this should be working as well:
[ng-include with a variable for src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860225/ng-include-with-a-variable-for-src)

Havent tested yet, if not working, please make a plunker for easy helping

Edit:

`<ng-include src="content.src"/>` is the way to go

Comment: it does also not work: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{ content.src }}] starting at [{ content.src }}].`

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/326det/how_do_i_use_nginclude_with_a_variable_in_src/

According to this article: remove the {{}} signs. Still could not test that

Comment: `<ng-include src="content.src"/>`helps, thank you. Would you update your answer, so that I can mark it as correct answer?

Comment: Someone else was faster.. :/